# Really Cool Power Series Coefficient Problem

Tags: power-series

Hi everyone :) We learnt what a power series is in class, but that coefficient thing is new. How do we find coefficients of power series using that equation? What do we do?

[image: Power Series]

If someone can help me with any hints on (a), that would be great. I'll do my best for the rest. Thanks lots.

UPDATE:Thanks to @Macavity, I did get to this point:

$$\frac{\left(a_{k-2}+Axa_{k-2}+a_k+Aa_{k-1}\right)}{a_{k-2}}\sum _{k=0}^{infinity}a_kx^k$$

But what do I do next?

Comment: Just multiply the LHS term by term and sum.

Comment: Hey @Macavity thanks! But I'm really stuck. :'(

Comment: @Macavity I did multiply them out but then how can I cancel out the $B$ variable?

Comment: Use the recursion for eliminating that. If you post your attempt, it will be easy for someone to help you correct or complete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\eqalign{(1+Ax+Bx^2)\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\bigl(a_k x^k+Aa_k x^{k+1}+Ba_k x^{k+2}\bigr)\cr&=\sum_{k=0}a_k x^k+\sum_{k'=1}^\infty Aa_{k'-1}x^{k'}+\sum_{k'=2}^\infty Ba_{k'-2}x^{k'}\cr
&=\ldots+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\bigl(a_k+Aa_{k-1}+Ba_{k-2}\bigr)x^k\ .\cr}$$
Now take care of the terms incorporated in the $\ \ldots\ $.

Comment: Thank you, Professor Blatter. May I please ask - for the last two terms in the second step, did you take the derivative? And how to expand the whole thing to obtain the "..." part?

Comment: No derivatives, just arranging,  re-indexing, and re-collecting terms. Some terms of the first two sums in the second line do not appear in the sum beginning with $k=2$ in the third line. They should be taken care of separately where the $\ldots\ $ are.

Comment: That helped! Professor, could you have a look at my working below? I don't know what I need to do here.
$$\sum _{k=0}^{infinity}a_kx^k+\sum _{k=0}^{infinity}Aa_kx^{\left(k+1\right)}+\sum _{k=0}^{infinity}Ba_kx^{\left(k+2\right)}$$
$$Aa_0x+Ba_0x^2+Ba_1x^3+\sum _{k=0}^{infinity}a_kx^k+\sum _{k=1}^{infinity}Aa_{k-1}x^{\left(k\right)}+\sum _{k=2}^{infinity}Ba_{k-2}x^{\left(k\right)}$$ Apologies for the repeated edits, I'm clearly bad with MathJax.